# List of political blogs

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, text

I'm analyzing political texts and I need the writings of random political authors.

So far I found a dataset of four political blogs normalized for text analysis. But that's not enough.

I thought about RSS of political blogs. [Feedly](http://feedly.com/i/explore/%23politics) and [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/tag/wordpress-political-blogs) have these categories, but no convenient way of extracting RSS feeds or even the list of the blogs. The same for [Dmoz](http://www.dmoz.org/News/Weblogs/).

Do you have any ideas where such a list of RSS feeds (or blogs) might be? Or only crawling may help?

Comment: Fwiw, although you may have considered this already (I can't entirely tell from your question), most Wordpress blogs will have their RSS feeds at a common address.

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog that lists political blogs based in the US:

http://politicalbloglistings.blogspot.ch/

Categories (count of listed blogs):

- Conservative (108)
- Liberal (70)
- Non/Bi-Partisan or Independent/Moderate (11)
- Libertarian (14)
- Green (1)
- Humor (3)
- Region Specific (1)
- Issue Specific (2)
- Uncategorized (104)

The list is originally from 2005, but many that I checked are still active.